# Modifying Navbar in Ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am trying to add 3 columns to my ionic navbar and it does not work.
Here is my code:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark nav-title-slide-ios7">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
        <div class=row>
            <div class="col"> Andreea </div>
            <div class="col"> Kate</div>
            <div class="col"> Andi </div>
        </div>  
      </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Would you rather do it as a list (ul, li)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using `ion-header-bar` instead of `ion-nav-bar` since it allows for quite a bit more customization. (It will work with multiple columns such as those in your code.)  You would, however, lose the ui-router integration built into `ion-nav-bar` which would require you to handle said navigation yourself.  See this page for further explanation: [Navigating Ionic's Headers](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-bar-vs-header-bar/).  Here's the gist from the article's conclusion:

> A standard header bar serves on its own as a pure UI element, ready for extension based on the developer’s needs, but doesn’t come with the advanced integration into Ionic’s router and navigation stack. The nav bar is far more opinionated in its use, but offers a lot of power in return.